# How do i convert this Series to a nested json string?

Tags: python, json, pandas, series

So i have this Series object called `ss`:

```
In [137]: d
Out[137]: {'-1': 24.0, '-2': 0.0, '-3': 0.0}

In [138]: ss = pd.Series(d)

In [139]: ss
Out[139]: 
-1    24.0
-2     0.0
-3     0.0
dtype: float64
```

How do i get a json string in the following shape?

```
[
{
  "y": 24.0,
  "x": -1
},
{
  "y": 0.0,
  "x": -2       
},
{
  "y": 0.0,
  "x": -3
}
]
```

I've tried the following, but it's not what is expected.

```
In [142]: result = json.loads(ss.to_json())

In [143]: result
Out[143]: {u'-1': 24.0, u'-2': 0.0, u'-3': 0.0}
```

---

EDIT: per the comment from Anton vBR, i'm trying with a DataFrame:

```
In [151]: dd = {'-1': [24.0], '-2': [0.0], '-3': [0.0]}

In [153]: df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

In [154]: df
Out[154]: 
     -1   -2   -3
0  24.0  0.0  0.0

In [156]: df.to_dict()
Out[156]: {'-1': {0: 24.0}, '-2': {0: 0.0}, '-3': {0: 0.0}}

In [157]: df.to_json()
Out[157]: '{"-1":{"0":24.0},"-2":{"0":0.0},"-3":{"0":0.0}}'
```

But it's still not close to what i need.

Comment: You need to make a dataframe out of it.

Comment: If your desired output is a list of dictionaries, why convert to a series at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

d = {'-1': 24.0, '-2': 0.0, '-3': 0.0}
ss = pd.Series(d)

result = json.dumps([{"x": k, "y": v} for k, v in ss.items()])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{"x": "-1", "y": 24.0}, {"x": "-2", "y": 0.0}, {"x": "-3", "y": 0.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the idea here is to go directly to a DataFrame by accessing your dictionaries keys and values through the `items()` function.

Let us call the columns `x` and `y` to get desired output.

**updated** for json output

```
import json
import pandas as pd

d = {'-1': 24.0, '-2': 0.0, '-3': 0.0}
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['x','y'])
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'])
dout = json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='records'), indent=2)
# "[{"y": 0.0, "x": -2.0}, {"y": 0.0, "x": -3.0}, {"y": 24.0, "x": -1.0}]" with indent None

print(dout)
```

Returns

```
[
  {
    "y": 0.0,
    "x": -2.0
  },
  {
    "y": 0.0,
    "x": -3.0
  },
  {
    "y": 24.0,
    "x": -1.0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First transform your Series to Dataframe, then use a built in method on Dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['x','y']).to_json(orient='records')
```